# SQL Server stored procedure date

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a procedure which add new data in a table.

The name of the table is in the paramaters.

The error is

> The data types varchar(max) and date are incompatible in the add operator.

The date field must be type `date`.

**PROCEDURE**

```
USE [ProposalBuilderDev]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addLog] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @table varchar(max), 
    @date date,
    @version varchar(max),
    @process varchar(max),
    @level varchar(max),
    @message varchar(max),
    @stacktrace varchar(max),
    @user varchar(max),
    @environmentID varchar(max),
    @UUID varchar(max),
    @UDID varchar(max),
    @transactionID int,
    @new_identity int OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO dbo.' + @table + '([Timestamp], [Version],Process,[Level],[Message],StackTrace,[User],EnvironmentID,UUID,UDID,TransactionID) VALUES (' + @date + ',' + @version + ',' + @process + ','+ @level + ','+ @message + ','+ @stacktrace + ','+ @user + ','+ @environmentID + ','+ @UUID + ','+ @UDID + ',' + @transactionID + ')'
    EXEC @sql

    SET @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Comment: I found this because the name of the table is in the parameter. If you have another way to do it, I can change

Comment: all your tables have the same column specification and datatype?

Comment: Yes, they are all the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pleas try to use `CAST()`

`... + CAST(@date AS VARCHAR(MAX) + ...`

Also, using `sp_executesql` would be a better and safer approach.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL =  ' INSERT INTO dbo.' + @Table;
SET @SQL += '   ([Timestamp], [Version],Process,[Level],[Message],StackTrace,[User],EnvironmentID,UUID,UDID,TransactionID)';
SET @SQL += ' VALUES';
SET @SQL += '   (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10);';

EXECUTE sp_executesql
      @SQL
    , N'@p0 DATE, @p1 VARCHAR(MAX), @p2 VARCHAR(MAX), @p3 VARCHAR(MAX), @p4 VARCHAR(MAX), @p5 VARCHAR(MAX), @p6 VARCHAR(MAX), @p7 VARCHAR(MAX), @p8 VARCHAR(MAX), @p9 VARCHAR(MAX), @p10 VARCHAR(MAX)'
    , @p0 = @date
    , @p1 = @version
    , @p2 = @process
    , @p3 = @level
    , @p4 = @message
    , @p5 = @stacktrace
    , @p6 = @user
    , @p7 = @environmentID
    , @p8 = @UUID
    , @p9 = @UDID
    , @p10 = @transactionID;
```

Just specify correct column data types in 3rd line.

Comment: The date field must be "date". I can't cast it in varchar. If there is avsolutely no other way to do it, i'll use your answer. thx

Comment: The date will be in format, that your table has. Error is thrown because you're generating a `Dynamic SQL Code` and it has to be constructed from VARCHAR. Also, I would also give a look at sp_executesql

Comment: @Weedoze I've modified my answer with better and safer approach. Please try that.